# New to Bootstrap 4, Columns are not acting as they should?

Tags: html, css

I have limited experience with Bootstrap 4 but am not sure why my page is acting like this. I have these 2 rows, one of which I want for the title to be above the container with white background. I am trying to make 2 columns, one for a sidebar and one for the content on the right however when I use columns they only stack which can be seen here - http://michaelfroseth.com/clients/notebook-html/subpage.html

I have no idea why? They seem to operate fine outside of the row, but am I not supposed to be using a new row? Any documentation or point in the right direction would be much appreciated!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/custom.css?v=2">
<title>Pam's Notebook | V1.0</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1 class="display-5"><span style="color:#fff;">Pam's Notebook</span> <span style="color:#CCAC23;">V1.0</span></h1>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="login-container col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-4">SIDEBAR</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ALL OF YOUR SITE CODE HERE -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- ADDITIONAL JS HERE -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `row` inside the container, not as a wrapper.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/custom.css?v=2">
<title>Pam's Notebook | V1.0</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1 class="display-5"><span style="color:#fff;">Pam's Notebook</span> <span style="color:#CCAC23;">V1.0</span></h1>
    </div>  
  </div>
    <div class="login-container col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">SIDEBAR</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ALL OF YOUR SITE CODE HERE -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- ADDITIONAL JS HERE -->
</body>
</html>
```